# hyperlink trouble in php echo'd table

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo

I"m having trouble with my code hopefully someone can help.

I'm trying to call information using "php echo" to display information in table form and it works except for the links which doesn't recognize the $id.  If I don't put it in the table form it works fine but it is not aesthetically appealing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("location: ../index.php");
exit();
}
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once("../scripts/connect.php");
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
echo 'Do you really want to delete messages with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] .'? <a     href="admin_messages.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="admin_messages.php">No</a>';
exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    // delete from database
$id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `mystore`.`messages` WHERE `messages`.`id` =     '$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
}
$messages = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY msg_date DESC LIMIT 20");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['msg_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['msg_email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['msg_subject'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['msg_date'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="mailto: '.$row['msg_email'].'">Reply</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="admin_messages.php?deleteid=$id">Delete</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
}else{
$messages = "<b>There are no messages in the database at this moment</b>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin Messages</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/forms.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" media="screen">
</head>
 <body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">
        <?php include_once("templates/tmp_header.php"); ?>
        <?php include_once("templates/tmp_nav.php"); ?>   
        <section id="main_content">
        <h2 class="page_title">Messages</h2>
        <br/>
        <table width="730" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="100">From</td>
                <td align="center" width="300">Email</td>
                <td align="center" width="300">Subject</td>
                <td align="center" width="100">Date</td>
                <td align="center" width="100">Actions</td
            ></tr>
            <?php echo $messages; ?>
        </table>
    </section>
    <?php include_once("templates/tmp_aside.php"); ?>
    <?php include_once("templates/tmp_footer.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **NOTE - MYSQL FUNCTIONS ARE DEPRECATED. PLEASE USE PREPARED STATEMENTS USING MYSQLI OR PDO. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php**

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
echo '<td><a href="admin_messages.php?deleteid=$id">Delete</a></td>';
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href='admin_messages.php?deleteid=$id'>Delete</a></td>";
```

when trying to print out a variable the main string has to be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interpolate variables in PHP, you need to use double quotes. `echo '$id'` will literally print `$id`, whereas `echo "$id"` will print the value of the variable. However, I would recommend an alternative approach. Don't use PHP where it isn't needed. There's no need to use `echo` so much.

I would change the contents of your loop to this:

```
?>
<tr>
  <td><?=$row['msg_name']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['msg_email']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['msg_subject']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['msg_date']?></td>
  <td><a href="mailto:<?=$row['msg_email']?>">Reply</a></td>
  <td><a href="admin_messages.php?deleteid=<?=$id?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
```

The `<?=$id?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo $id?>` and is [supported by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in PHP versions >=5.4.0. You can also use it in previous versions if you enable short_open_tags.

As stated in the comments, you should really be using `mysqli` functions, as `mysql` functions are deprecated.